# Replace all non digits with a restriction

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'm trying to extract the first number from expressions:

Here's my code for while:

```
String[] strArray = input.split("\\+ ");
double[] numbers = getNumbersFromString();

public static double[] getNumbersFromString() {
   double[] numbers = new double[strArray.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(strArray[i].replaceAll("\\D", ""));
   }

   return numbers;
}
```

## Inputs and their expected outputs:

- Z = 4x1 + 3x2 + 6x3 // 4 3 6
- Z = 24x1 + 33x2 + 68x3 // 24 33 68
- Z = 412x1 + 309x2 + 612x3 // 412 309 612
- Z = 4329x1 + 3901x2 + 6716x3 // 4329 3901 6716

Actually, it's removing but it retrieves besides the first number, the second also. Eg.(In the first case): // 41 32 63, while it should be only // 4 3 6.

I could do something like `"\\w = |x\\d", ""`, but it will only work for this specific case, I want a more general thing.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit:

I got the following answer for the original question:

```
String input = "Z = 4329x1 + 3901x22 + 6716x3";
input = input.replaceAll("^\\D+", "");
double[] numbers = Pattern.compile("x\\d+\\D*")
                      .splitAsStream(input)
                      .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                      .toArray();
```

But now appeared a new thing to be done. Inputs that has no numbers before the `x1/x2/x3`.. or any kind of this" should be replaced by the number "1".

**Some inputs and their respective expected outputs:**

- Z = x11 + x2 + x90 // 1 1 1
- Z = 2x1 + 2x4 + x9 // 2 2 1

By the way, I have made this regex: `(?<!\d)x\d+`.

Then I modified the code to:

```
return Pattern.compile("x\\d+\\D*")
                .splitAsStream(input.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)x\\d+","1").replaceAll("^\\D+", ""))
                .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                .toArray();
```

But it's returning me `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 + 3".

PS: it should work for either the old and new case.

Comment: Shouldn't your method `getNumbersFromString` take the array as an argument?

Comment: Yes, I just simplified the code.

Comment: So the **first number** is always followed by `x` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as required:

```
String s = "Z = 4329x1 + 3901x22 + 6716x3";
String[] split = s.replaceAll("^\\D+", "").split("x\\d+\\D*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split)); //[4329, 3901, 6716]
```

With streams you could do something like this to obtain your array of doubles:

```
String input = "Z = 4329x1 + 3901x22 + 6716x3";
input = input.replaceAll("^\\D+", "");
double[] numbers = Pattern.compile("x\\d+\\D*")
                          .splitAsStream(input)
                          .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                          .toArray();
```

---

#### EDIT

To also accept expressions such as `x1 + x2`, you can default to `1` when the string returned by split is empty (and amend the regex slightly):

```
String input = "Z = x1 + x2 + 6716x3";
input = input.replaceAll("^[^x\\d]+", "");
double[] numbers = Pattern.compile("x\\d+[^x\\d]*")
        .splitAsStream(input)
        .mapToDouble(s -> s.isEmpty() ? 1d : Double.parseDouble(s))
        .toArray();
```

---

#### RE-EDIT

Add the missing 1 before the x manually:

```
String input = "Z = x1 + x2 + 6716x3 + x4";
input = input.replace(" x", " 1x")
             .replaceAll("^[^x\\d]+", "");

double[] numbers = Pattern.compile("x\\d+[^x\\d]*")
        .splitAsStream(input)
        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
        .toArray();
```

Comment: It gives me error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Z = 4"`

Comment: It works, but how can I get it as array of `double`?

Comment: @assylias Nice use of streams again. Thank you. +1

Comment: @assylias, Appeared a new thing to be done. Inputs that has no numbers before the `x1/x2/x3`.. or any kind of this" should be replaced by the number "1". I have made this regex: `(?<!\d)x\d+`. Then consider the inputs: `[x11 + x2 + x90] [2x1 + 2x4 + x9]`, the output should be: `[1 1 1] [2 2 1]`, understand me? Sorry for taking your time again, but can you help me with that? By the way, it should work for either cases (that you posted and the new case I described). Can you take a look at the edit?

Comment: The most of inputs are working, but for some reason it won't work if that kind of expressions appears in the end of the String. **Eg.:** `[x1 + 2x2 + x3]` `[2x4 - 3x9 + x5]` returns me just `[1  2]` and `[2 3]`.

Comment: @developer033 updated - note that now that you have the basic logic in place you can play around with the code and adapt it to your needs...

Comment: Thanks. Well, I tried to understand these regex's but I have to admit I didn't understand much what they did, that's why I was it was hard to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pattern is a number followed by an `x`, using `positive lookahead` like this will work.

**Regex:** `\d+(?=x)`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=x)` looks ahead and checks if `x` is present. If yes then `\d+` is matched.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uH1eB4/1)**

**Note:** Use double escape `\\d` if necessary.

Comment: It returns me error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Z = x1"`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the whole grabbing in a single regex (per row which I assume from your example what you're interested in) -

```
(?:=|\+)\s*(\d+)
```

It matches either a `=` or a `+`, skipping any spaces and then **captures** the number. Make it global and it'll capture the entire row. The result will be in the capture group array. (Don't speak java well enough to tell you exactly how from the top of my head).

[Check it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hK0lI3/1). (Note - sample shows all the rows at once - you'd have to do them one by one.)